# the starter function "npm start" fails to start up react development server on all react projects

Tags: reactjs, node.js, visual-studio-code, cmd

i tried opening my react project just now with "npm start" but it doesn't start the project as it should instead, it shows "'"node"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." each time i try.

i already tried asking chatgpt on how to solve this issue and it had said to try certain things which i have tried and i also tried uninstalling the node from my system and reinstalling it but i still faced this same problem. i also tried doing the "sudo npm install react-scripts -g" both in the windows terminal (cmd) and in the vscode's terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working on git bash as your terminal, try changing to powershell or cmd. This worked for me.